# What's the point of using "w" mode in python?

Tags: python

```
#From the sys package, i'm importing the argv
from sys import argv
#Un packaging the arguments
script, filename = argv 
#Print statements
print "We're going to erase %r." % filename
print "If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C)."
print "If you do want that, hit RETURN."
#To accept whether or not we want to continue or not
raw_input("?")

print "Opening the file..."
# I am opening the file
target = open(filename)

print "Truncating the file. Goodbye!"
target.truncate()

print "Now i'm going to ask you for three lines."

line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")

print "I'm going to write these to the file."
x = "%r\n %r\n %r\n" % (line1, line2, line3)
target.write(x)
#This also works to write the files
# target.write ("%r\n%r\n%r\n" % (line1, line2, line3))

print "And finally, we close it."
target.close()
```

For the `open(filename)`, I find I get the same result when I put the script in action as `open(filename "w")`

What is the point of "w" then? Since I already have a function to write with the target.write() command!

Comment: Side note: use `with open(filename) as target:` instead of manual closing. This ensures exception-safety. See [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/).

Answer (score 6):

"w" mode creates the file if it does not exist, and empties it if it does.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the docs for `open()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open):

> The most commonly-used values of mode are 'r' for reading, 'w' for writing (truncating the file if it already exists), and 'a' for appending (which on some Unix systems means that all writes append to the end of the file regardless of the current seek position). If mode is omitted, it defaults to 'r'.